# Module iCloudStorage requires main queue setup since it overrides `constantsToExport`

Tags: ios, react-native, storage, icloud, icloud-api

When launching my iOS App built with react-native, I get the following warning:

> Module iCloudStorage requires main queue setup since it overrides
> `constantsToExport` but doesn't implement `requiresMainQueueSetup`. In
> a future release React Native will default to initializing all native
> modules on a background thread unless explicitly opted-out of.

I've been searching around to find a solution but the only thing I found was this:

> add requiresMainQueueSetup to prevent warning and future side-effects
> in RCCManagerModule

It says I should add the following snippet to `ios/RCCManagerModule.m`

```js
(BOOL)requiresMainQueueSetup
{
    return YES;
}
```

There is **no** `RCCManagerModule.m` file in my react-native project.

Is there any other solution to this?

And if possible, could someone explain me what does this error actually says/means: what is main queue setup in this context?

Comment: did you figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

Currently the maintainer of react-native-audio has said he's not maintaining the project anymore, so it is unlikely to be fixed unless someone volunteers to take over maintenance. Apparently it should not affect behavior.  See [this discussion](https://github.com/jsierles/react-native-audio/issues/283).

But as shown on [the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tDVFfMZDoDc) mentioned in the above discussion, you can go to node_modules/react-native-audio/ios/AudioRecorderManager.m, and before the line `- (void)stopProgressTimer {`, insert this code:

```
+ (BOOL) requiresMainQueueSetup {
  return YES;
}
```

That eliminates the warning.